# Browser going "Back" by itself

Tags: browser, google-pixel-4

having a super weird issue with Google Pixel 4 XL.

Since yesterday my Chrome (tried later on Brave and something wild like Vivaldi) is acting out.

Opening new tab and going to website like facebook.com/instagram.com/index.hr would start loading the site then as soon as it is loaded it would return back to starting page. In the tab I can go "Forward" to were I was before but it would again go back.
Nice thing about it is that some websites like google.com/poslovni.hr work completely normal and this is not happening.

Then later that day all websites worked normal but now couple of hours later I open same tab again and it literally went back in history page by page to the beginning of the tab.

I've updated to latest Android, restarted, cleaned cache but no help.
Initially was thinking it's Chrome issue but seems that it's on mobile level because it's happening on all installed browsers.

Any idea on what to do in this case?

Comment: Web browser often use one process per tab. When the browser "goes back" this could mean that the tab process has crashed. As Chrome, Brave and Vivaldi all base on Chromium it is not unlikely that all three are affected by this problem.

Comment: @Robert are there any browsers not based on Chromium? I've tried Edge and Firefox now... Tor Browser seem to work tho. So can I do something about my Chromium issues?

Comment: Firefox and Tor Browser both should use the Firefox based rendering engine.